# ib_insync errors when running codes

Tags: python

Am having the following errors whenever i run codes in the ide after following all instructions to setup ib_insync

John

1.

```
import ib_insync
print(ib_insync.__all__)
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-473401a31836> in <module>
      import ib_insync
      print(ib_insync.__all__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ib_insync'
```

2. 

```
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()
```

---

```
ModuleNotFoundError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-eaa7c0a329d2> in <module>
       from ib_insync import *
       util.startLoop()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ib_insync'
```

Comment: Did you actually install `ib_insync` for the interpreter used to run this code?

Answer (score 0):

The import is failing.

You either didn't install the module correctly, or you are trying to run your script in the wrong environment (make sure the IDE is running your code in the same place you installed the module).